# How to extract match from regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text of the following format:

```
let text = "help me on monday, january 8 take the dog out";
```

Basically, a sentence with possibly a `<weekday-date>` combination.

I want to

1. Recognize if the sentence has a weekday-date combination
2. extract the weekday-date combination (so monday, january 8)
3. delete the weekday name (so january 8)

**For 1, I was able to achieve this via the following**

```
const weekdayRegex = /\b((mon|tues|wed(nes)?|thur(s)?|fri|sat(ur)?|sun)(day)?)\b/;
const monthThenDayRegex = /(jan(uary)?|feb(ruary)?|mar(ch)?|apr(il)?|may|jun(e)?|jul(y)?|aug(ust)?|sep(tember)?|oct(ober)?|nov(ember)?|dec(ember)?) *\d{1,2}(th|nd|st|rd){0,1}/;
const dayDayThenMonthRegex = /d{1,2}(th|nd|st|rd){0,1} *(of){0,1} *(jan(uary)?|feb(ruary)?|mar(ch)?|apr(il)?|may|jun(e)?|jul(y)?|aug(ust)?|sep(tember)?|oct(ober)?|nov(ember)?|dec(ember)?)/;
```

Then:

```
commaSeperated = new RegExp(weekdayRegex.source + " *,{0,1} *" + monthThenDayRegex.source);
commaSeperated.test(text)
```

This works, I get true

For step 2, how do I extract "monday, january 8"

For step 3, how do I just keep "january 8"?

Comment: `text.match(commaSeperated)` to get started. You can also use "".split(), which keeps the non-parens, which can be handy sometime. the 2nd part is easier with low-level methods: `"monday, january 8".split(/,\s+/).pop()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**match**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for these purposes

```
const text = "help me on monday, january 8 take the dog out";    
const weekdayRegex = /\b((mon|tues|wed(nes)?|thur(s)?|fri|sat(ur)?|sun)(day)?)\b/;
const monthThenDayRegex = /(jan(uary)?|feb(ruary)?|mar(ch)?|apr(il)?|may|jun(e)?|jul(y)?|aug(ust)?|sep(tember)?|oct(ober)?|nov(ember)?|dec(ember)?) *\d{1,2}(th|nd|st|rd){0,1}/;
const commaSeperated = new RegExp(weekdayRegex.source + " *,{0,1} *" + monthThenDayRegex.source);


expect(commaSeperated.test(text)).toEqual(true);
expect(text.match(commaSeperated)[0]).toEqual('monday, january 8');
expect(text
       .match(commaSeperated)[0]
       .match(monthThenDayRegex)[0]).toEqual('january 8');
```

https://jsbin.com/repexux/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

I made a small simplification to your `commaSeparated` regex - `{0,1}` is the same as `?`

```js
let text = "help me on monday, january 8 take the dog out";
const weekdayRegex = /\b((mon|tues|wed(nes)?|thur(s)?|fri|sat(ur)?|sun)(day)?)\b/;
const monthThenDayRegex = /(jan(uary)?|feb(ruary)?|mar(ch)?|apr(il)?|may|jun(e)?|jul(y)?|aug(ust)?|sep(tember)?|oct(ober)?|nov(ember)?|dec(ember)?) *\d{1,2}(th|nd|st|rd){0,1}/;
const dayDayThenMonthRegex = /d{1,2}(th|nd|st|rd){0,1} *(of){0,1} *(jan(uary)?|feb(ruary)?|mar(ch)?|apr(il)?|may|jun(e)?|jul(y)?|aug(ust)?|sep(tember)?|oct(ober)?|nov(ember)?|dec(ember)?)/;

const commaSeperated = new RegExp(weekdayRegex.source + " *,? *" + monthThenDayRegex.source);

const m = text.match(commaSeperated);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[0]);
  console.log(m[0].replace(/^.+, */,''))
} else {
  console.log('not a match');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified (complicated?) your regexps by splitting `monthThenDayRegex` and `dayDayThenMonthRegex` into separate `monthRegex` and `dayOfMonthRegex` regexps, then joining them together again inside `dateRegex`. I've also added preceding `^.*?` and trailing `.*$` to match the beginning and end of the string to allow the use of [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to extract the date parts. As shown in the snippet, you can also use `dateRegex.test()` to check if the string matches the regexp before processing it.

```js
const weekdayRegex = /\b((?:mon|tues|wed(?:nes)?|thur(?:s)?|fri|sat(?:ur)?|sun)(?:day)?)\b/;
const monthRegex = /\b(jan(?:uary)?|feb(?:ruary)?|mar(?:ch)?|apr(?:il)?|may|jun(?:e)?|jul(?:y)?|aug(?:ust)?|sep(?:tember)?|oct(?:ober)?|nov(?:ember)?|dec(?:ember)?)\b/;
const dayOfMonthRegex = /\b\d{1,2}(?:th|nd|st|rd)?\b/;
const dateRegex = new RegExp('^.*?' + weekdayRegex.source + '\\W+((' + monthRegex.source + '\\s+' + dayOfMonthRegex.source + ')|(' + dayOfMonthRegex.source + '\\s+(of\\s+)?' + monthRegex.source + ')).*$', 'i');
let strings = ["help me on monday, january 8 take the dog out","today is tuesday 12th of november", "I like wednesday Feb 11, it's my birthday!", "Sun jan 5th", "january 8", "12th of november"];
strings.map(text => { console.log(dateRegex.test(text) ? text.replace(dateRegex, '$2') : text + ' didn\'t match!'); });
```